# AJAX call, possibly mobile device issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, paypal

I am using PayPal for payment transactions. Since the system has been up and running there has been one particular problem. Most of the time the order is recorded in my DB, but occasionally it isn't.

When a user hits checkout, normally a form would be posted to PayPal with all the items in, but it may attempt to track down the problem the code on the Checkout button is now this:-

```
    $.get('insertOrder.php', function(data) {
        //alert("Server Returned: " + data);
    });         

      $( "#paypal_checkout" ).submit();

    });
```

so basically pressing the button should run my `insertOrder.php` script, then begin the PayPal process, and most of the time it works fine.

I have the `IPN` service set up so I get a confirmation email telling me they have taken payment, providing the order was stored at checkout, the `basketID` is matched up and the `Transaction ID` added to the order in my `DB`.

But I get confirmations come through for payments that have no corresponding order in my DB, when testing on my desktop and mobile everything worked as it should all of the time.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening or the best way to debug this.

NB: I know the best way to store orders is only after payment has completed, I have only done it this way to try to understand why orders are not being stored, but payment is being taken.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: If the `submit()` is causing a pageunload event (ie. not an AJAX request) I'd strongly suggest you place it in the callback of `$.get()`. Your current logic would be dependant on the race condition where the AJAX needs to be quick enough to not be aborted as the page changes.

Comment: so to claify something like this:-

            $.get('insertOrder.php', function($( "#paypal_checkout" ).submit()) {
                //alert("Server Returned: " + data);
            });

Comment: Yep, although your example there has a syntax error as you placed the `submit()` in the arguments of the anonymous function instead of the body.

Comment: sorry, jquery isnt' my strongest suit, so like this -             $.get('insertOrder.php', $( "#paypal_checkout" ).submit() {
               
            });

Comment: `$.get('insertOrder.php', function() { $('#paypal_checkout').submit(); });`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a whirl.